# What is best way to use Windows XP laptop/netbook as a dummy client to Windows 7 desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'd like to use my laptop remote desktop into my desktop.  What's the best way to do this?

Just Windows RDP?  What about my IP address at home being changed by my ISP?  Should I use DynDNS?

Or is it worth paying the extra money for a commercial RDP solution like [LapLink](http://www.laplink.com)?

Note: My laptop runs XP and my desktop Win 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use DynDNS or go for **[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)**, then it doesn't matter when your IP changes.

Install **Teamviewer Host** as a service on your home computer, use **Teamviewer Portable** to connect to your computer at home from anywhere.

*Teamviewer is free for personal use.*

easy to use (literally no configuration required), very fast and excellent quality.

Answer (score 0):

TightVNC! It comes with a server and a viewer. Just launch the server on the desktop and the viewer on the laptop. I'm pretty sure that your IP being changed will have any effect.

Comment: Is that true?  TightVNC does not care if your ip address is changed?

Comment: no, you'll need DynDNS or a static IP for TightVNC ... or RealVNC ... or UltraVNC

Comment: Do the various VNC server/clients still need an SSH tunnel to secure the traffic?

Comment: my ISP changes my IP every month and I seem to have no problems